# JavaScript - Capitalize each word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, capitalize

I am trying to capitalize each word in a sentence in JavaScript.
When ran I get an Uncaught TypeError saying myArray.substr is not a function.

```
function cap() {
    var myString, myArray, first, last, up, low;
    myString = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    myArray = myString.split(" ");
    first = myArray.substr(0, 1);
    last = first.substr(1);
    up = myString.toUpperCase();
    low = myString.toLowerCase();

    document.getElementById("textbox").value = myString;

    return cap(" ");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the split function is not returning an array in some circumstances

Comment: `.substr` is a function on strings, not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42755730/3140312). This worked for me. I used what was mentioned,

```
return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function toTitleCase()
    {
        var myString = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
        return myString.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
    }
```