# How to make first word first character capital of each sentence

Tags: javascript

I want first word first character capital of each sentence. My code only capitalizing first word, first character of para. So I want to capitalize first word, first character after full stop and exclamation mark.

**Example(I want this)**:

1. hello I haven't seen you for awhile! how are you! --> Hello I haven't seen you for awhile! How are you!
2. hello I haven't seen you for awhile. how are you. --> Hello I haven't seen you for awhile. How are you.

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1eb5d0ng/):**

**Code:**

**Html Code:**

```
<textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput" name="message" oninput="myFunction()" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
<br><br>
<input id="FistWordFirstCharcterCapital" onclick="FistWordFirstCharcterCapital()" style="color: black;" type="button" value="First word first character capital of each sentence!" />
```

**Javascript code**

```
<script>
    function FistWordFirstCharcterCapital() {
      var string = document.getElementById("TextInput").value.toLowerCase();;
      var x = string.replace(string[0], string[0].toUpperCase());
      document.getElementById("TextInput").value = x;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: const toTitleCase = s => s.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase();

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755664/capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-in-js

Comment: In css write  
  .capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}  

In JavaScript, you can add the class to an element

 document.getElementById("element").className = "capitalize";

Comment: @Satish Hawalppagol I wan first word first character capital of each sentence. I mean whatever word comes after full stop and exclamation mark I want it should be capital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try splitting the sentences first. Then map them to uppercase only the first letter like the following way:

```js
function FistWordFirstCharcterCapital() {
  var el = document.getElementById("TextInput");
  el.value = el.value.split(/[.?!]/).map(str =>{ 
    if(str.charAt(0) == ' ') 
      return ' ' + str.charAt(1).toUpperCase() + str.slice(2);
    else 
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  }).join('.');
}
```

```html
<textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput" name="message" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
<br><br>

<input id="FistWordFirstCharcterCapital" onclick="FistWordFirstCharcterCapital()" style="color: black;" type="button" value="First word first character capital of each sentence!" />
```

Comment: Thanks, still their is the problem after paragraph changes this not making second paragraph first word, first character capital.